# RegEx matcing numeric values with or without thousand separators

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx to match the following:

```
1.234.567
-1.234.789
1234567
-1234567
```

It should not match:

```
.123     (leading separator)
123..456 (two separators)
```

In other words, I need a RegEx to match `long` numeric values formatted with or without thousand separators.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the thousand seperator always a dot . ?

Comment: sounds a little like homework

Comment: Nope, it's not homework. I'm trying to ignore invalid user inputs from a TextBox in WPF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a more restricted answer

```
^-?(?!0)(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)$
```

See it online [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tu14)

`(?!0)` prevents from starting with 0

`\d+` allows the numbers without separator

`\d{1,3}(?:.\d{3})+` is the part for the separator. Start with 1 to 3 numbers, then a separator and 3 numbers. The dot for the separator followed by 3 numbers can be repeated.

Comment: Thanks! +1 for giving a more elaborate description.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like

```
^-?([0-9]{1,3}\.?)+$
```

[RegExr Demo](http://regexr.com?2tu0u)

Comment: Thanks! And a +1 for linking to demo with examples.

Comment: @Olav @bazmegakapa are you aware that this matches also `0.0.0`and `1.23.45` and `1.` ?

Comment: @stema I am. For client-side validation, it suffices. Yours is nicer of course, but a bit overkill to me.

Comment: Went with @stema's answer as it covers more what I was looking for.