# How to combine two regex's

Tags: regex

I want to combine these regex's so I can have the right result, my point is the regex should use ( or ) so if the number was "(45.29 SAR ) or ( 4,523.88 SAR)"

here is the two regex that i've used :

```
\b\d+\.\d+\p{Zs}+SAR\b

\b\d+\,\d+\.\d+\p{Zs}+SAR\b
```

[Example explain what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjm9O.png)

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need [`\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+\p{Zs}+SAR\b`](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9eC6/1). No round brackets, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx matcing numeric values with or without thousand separators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6248621/regex-matcing-numeric-values-with-or-without-thousand-separators)

Comment: Example goes here, as text, and not somewhere else in an image. How can we copy/paste the examples to use for testing if they're not in your question as text? Images should only be used when there is absolutely no other way to demonstrate an issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot man that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `*`-quantified group of a comma followed with 3 digits:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+\p{Zs}+SAR\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pZ9eC6/1)

Explanation:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0 or more groups of a comma followed with 3 digits
- `\.` - aliteral comma
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\p{Zs}+` - 1+ horizontal whitespace
- `SAR\b` - whole word `SAR`

Answer (score 0):

You also could try:

```
/\b\d+[.,]\d+(?:\.\d+)?\p{Zs}+SAR\b/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cJ1vF8/1)